# Can we access device photogallery from mobile device browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

In my project as per client we need to access and upload picture from photo gallery to site. It is for iOS, Android and blackberry. I know we can access it for android using opera browser but my question is can we access it for all mobile device and from any device browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact iOS even has multi-upload functionality built in as well. I'm not sure about blackberry, but I'm almost positive that any mobile device has this feature. The best thing you can do is just more research online and testing on them.

HTML(you don't need javascript to do it)

```
<input type="file"/>
```

Comment: Can we do that with single code or js file for all device at a time

Comment: @anupsharma sorry I had to log off last night. Anyways, I'll show you how to do it in my answer.